# Ubuntu 11.04 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, mysql

I have googled for 2 days now and was initially get a

```
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I fixed this by using:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld/
```

now i get the error:

```
 '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

So everything has the correct permissions and the file exists. Any thoughts?

**[Edit]**

Got it working, although i am unsure how. I did `aa-logprof` as `root`, nothing changed, got angry and then re-set it started working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot (absolutely cannot) replace the filesystem pipe `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock` with a regular file. You need to use `mkfifo(1)` to create the `pipe(7)` that clients use to communicate with the mysql server.

The `(13)` probably *also* means that you have a *permission denied* error return, `EACCES` (which usually has the decimal value `13` -- yes, I've seen it a lot).

If the file system permissions are configured correctly, you might be having accesses rejected by a  [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as  [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/).

AppArmor comes pre-installed on Ubuntu systems by default, and might be rejecting access to the pipe. Check `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `dmesg(1)` output for messages that look something like this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1320723925.179:45115): apparmor="DENIED"
operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/ntop"
name="/usr/share/ntop/html/PlotKit/excanvas.js" pid=1835 comm="ntop"
requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=122 ouid=0
```

(But with `name=/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock` instead.)

If you have error messages like this, run `aa-logprof` as `root` and answer the questions. More information on configuration AppArmor can be found in the `apparmor.d(5)` manpage, or some [various wiki pages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor).

Comment: Thanks the great reply. Always wish i spent more time with mysql rather than just queries.
So i get this error when i do mysql start "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)". Previously i had no problems starting mysql :/

Comment: 111104 11:54:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
111104 11:54:40  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
111104 11:54:40  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
111104 11:54:43  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
111104 11:54:44 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
111104 11:54:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.54-1ubuntu4'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu

Comment: Hey, that looks like an improvement; `111` is `Connection refused`. Did you restart the server after re-creating the socket? Is the server configured to use that pathname?

Comment: hummm ok so.. i restart the mysql server and get a lot of errors but the most appropriate i believe: 010101  1:37:56  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation. Also as for the pathname, i haven't actually edited any config for mysql, i just used sudo apt-get lamp-server

Comment: Got it working, although i am unsure how. I did aa-logprof, nothing changed, got angry and then re-set it started working. This almost made me more angry as now i don´t know the problem for next time :(.
Still thanks for the help

Comment: Dang. I'm always left with the same unsatisfied feeling when I don't find out the root cause of the problem. :( I'm glad it's working though.

Comment: I'm stock on the same problem with (13) error. Can't get it fixed even with the help here! :( I had the (2) problem, took care of it and everything was working fine. I restarted the server and now I get (13) not sure why... this is very annoying! :(

Comment: My issue was that bind address was changed. So I had to change that. I created a /.my.cnf file so that I don't have to change the configuration of mysql everytime the server restarts

Comment: Did the address change due to an upgrade that applied settings from `debconf(7)`?

Comment: mysql.sock is not a pipe/fifo, it's a local unix socket. _you_ cannot create that , the mysql server have to create it when it starts. (It might not if there's wrong permissions on the directory, or the server creates the socket in some other directory than where the clients look)

Comment: @nos: Thank you! I can't believe I've never looked at the socket before.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem after running an rsync command to restore a partial backup of certain file folders under the root filesystem (ie: `rsync -avc ${SOME_RESTORE_DIR}/ /` though not including `/var/lib/mysql` ).  In my case, the permissions of `/` were set to **700** after this operation, which prevented `mysqld` from starting. To fix it, I had to `chmod 755 /` and restart `mysqld`.  This probably would have caused many problems on the server too if not found ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, running `mysqld_safe` created a new `mysqld.sock` file.

```
$ cd /etc/init.d/
$ mysqld_safe
```

You'll probably won't get the prompt back, but if you restart your session, a mysqld.sock file will be somewhere. Find it with

```
$ sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Nice, I got this error (I guess) because I cancelled an alter table of a huge one, I didn't find any lock file but mysqld_safe fixed this! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the mysql server `mysqld` is running?  Also, check the system message log to see if it is complaining about anything.

Comment: It was running yes, although its not currently starting up. Seeing below comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove .lock file and restart mysqld ?

Comment: Where would this .lock file be?